# livequery not working in ie

Tags: php, jquery, html, livequery

hello friends i am working on a like module .and having some difficulties running it on ie . in all other browsers its running fine . the prob is when i click on like button nothing happens in ie . can anyone see my piece of code and help me out . IE is Such a pain .

```
           $('.LikeThis').livequery("click",function(e){

        var getID   =  $(this).attr('id').replace('post_id','');
        var uid = $('.like_uid').val();
        var type_id = $('.like_type_id').val();


        $("#shlike-loader-"+getID).html('<img src="images/icons/like.gif" alt="" />');

    $.post("eg?postId="+getID+ '&uid=' + uid + '&type_id=' + type_id, {


        }, function(response){
            $('#hiddenlikesval'+getID).remove();
            $('#likepanel'+getID).show();
            $('#likecontainer'+getID).append($(response).fadeIn('slow'));
            var bing=$('#hiddenlikesval'+getID).val();
            $('#lplbl'+getID).html(bing);
            $('#likePanel'+getID).css({'display':'block','width':'404px','padding':'5px 3px 5px 3px','background':'#ECEFF5'});
            $('#like-panel-'+getID).html('<input type="hidden" class="like_uid" id="like_uid'+getID+'" name="like_uid" value="'+uid+'"/><input type="hidden" class="like_type_id" id="like_type_id'+getID+'" name="like_type_id" value="'+type_id+'"/><div class="comtcontbtm unlwid"><a href="javascript: void(0)" id="post_id'+getID+'" class="Unlike liknlksh" title="Unlike"><span class="shareiconsbottom unlikeiconbtm"></span><span class="replyshare">unlike</span></a></div>');

            $("#shlike-loader-"+getID).html('');
        });
    });
```

Comment: `livequery` is deprecated.  You should use `.live()`.

Comment: @SLaks `live` is deprecated, you should use `on` or `delegate` (pre 1.7)

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Comment: can anyone help me with the code , and if its deprecated then why it working in all other browsers except IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using jQuery 1.7? If so, you should use `on`, `livequery` is deprecated. If you're using pre-1.7 you should use `.delegate`.

For 1.7 change your function declaration to:

```
$(document).on("click", ".LikeThis", function (e) {
    //your stuff here
});
```

For pre-1.7 change it to:

```
$(document).delegate("click", ".LikeThis", function (e) {
    //your stuff here
});
```

On: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Delegate: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: hello thnaks for the sample code i changed my whole code , but still the prob exist . in ie its not working

Comment: Hmm, can you post your markup in your question? Is there are an error thrown?

Comment: Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 1725
Char: 5
Code: 0

Comment: If you press "Yes" to debug in IE, what's the exact line that's throwing the error?

Comment: yes it is the exact line , for understanding the error i used developer version of jquery 1.7.2. still cant figure out whats the prob .

Comment: can anyone help me out in this

Comment: If you put your markup and your jQuery into a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ and provide me with the link I'll be able to help you.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me with the use of .on i found the solution , thr porblem was in the append line with the fadein effect , thanks for helping

Comment: Ah okay, no problems glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('.LikeThis').live('click', function (e) {
            var getID = $(this).attr('id').replace('post_id', '');
            var uid = $('.like_uid').val();
            var type_id = $('.like_type_id').val();


            $("#shlike-loader-" + getID).html('<img src="images/icons/like.gif" alt="" />');

            $.post("modules/like/likeit.php?postId=" + getID + '&uid=' + uid + '&type_id=' + type_id, {


            }, function (response) {
                $('#hiddenlikesval' + getID).remove();
                $('#likepanel' + getID).show();
                $('#likecontainer' + getID).append($(response).fadeIn('slow'));
                var bing = $('#hiddenlikesval' + getID).val();
                $('#lplbl' + getID).html(bing);
                $('#likePanel' + getID).css({ 'display': 'block', 'width': '404px', 'padding': '5px 3px 5px 3px', 'background': '#ECEFF5' });
                $('#like-panel-' + getID).html('<input type="hidden" class="like_uid" id="like_uid' + getID + '" name="like_uid" value="' + uid + '"/><input type="hidden" class="like_type_id" id="like_type_id' + getID + '" name="like_type_id" value="' + type_id + '"/><div class="comtcontbtm unlwid"><a href="javascript: void(0)" id="post_id' + getID + '" class="Unlike liknlksh" title="Unlike"><span class="shareiconsbottom unlikeiconbtm"></span><span class="replyshare">unlike</span></a></div>');

                $("#shlike-loader-" + getID).html('');
            });
        });
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated, you should use `on` or `delegate` (pre 1.7)

Comment: can anyone help me with a "on" i have never used it before